# How to pipe a string argument to an executable launched with Apache Commons Exec?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-exec

I need to pipe a text argument to the stdin of a command launched with Apache Commons Exec (for the curious, the command is gpg and the argument is the passphrase to the keystore; gpg does not have an argument to provide the passphrase explicitly, only to accept it from stdin).

In addition, I need this to support both Linux and Windows.

In a shell script I'd do

```
cat mypassphrase|gpg --passphrase-fd
```

or

```
type mypassphrase|gpg --passphrase-fd
```

but type doesn't work on Windows as it's not an executable but a command built into the command interpreted (cmd.exe).

The *code* not working (for the above reason) is below. To spawn an entire shell for this is too ugly, I was looking for a more elegant solution. Unfortunately, there are some incompatibility problems between the BouncyCastle library and PGP so I cannot use a fully programmatic solution in the (very short) time I have.

Thanks in advance.

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("type");
cmdLine.addArgument(passphrase);
cmdLine.addArgument("|");
cmdLine.addArgument("gpg");
cmdLine.addArgument("--passphrase-fd");
cmdLine.addArgument("0");
cmdLine.addArgument("--no-default-keyring");
cmdLine.addArgument("--keyring");
cmdLine.addArgument("${publicRingPath}");
cmdLine.addArgument("--secret-keyring");
cmdLine.addArgument("${secretRingPath}");
cmdLine.addArgument("--sign");
cmdLine.addArgument("--encrypt");
cmdLine.addArgument("-r");
cmdLine.addArgument("recipientName");
cmdLine.setSubstitutionMap(map);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

Answer (score 18):

You cannot add a pipe argument (`|`) because the `gpg` command won't accept that.  It's the shell (e.g. `bash`) that interprets the pipe and does special processing when you type that commandline into the shell.

You can use `ByteArrayInputStream` to manually send data to the standard input of a command (much like `bash` does when it sees the `|`).

```
    Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();

    CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("sed");
            cl.addArgument("s/hello/goodbye/");

    String text = "hello";
    ByteArrayInputStream input =
        new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    exec.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(output, null, input));
    exec.execute(cl);

    System.out.println("result: " + output.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
```

This should be the equivalent of typing `echo "hello" | sed s/hello/goodbye/` into a (`bash`) shell (though UTF-8 may be a more appropriate encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Hi to do this i will use a little helper class like this: https://github.com/Macilias/Utils/blob/master/ShellUtils.java

basically you can than simulate the pipe usage like shown here before without calling the bash beforehand:

```
public static String runCommand(String command, Optional<File> dir) throws IOException {
    String[] commands = command.split("\\|");
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    for (String cmd : commands) {
        output = runSubCommand(output != null ? new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray()) : null, cmd.trim(), dir);
    }
    return output != null ? output.toString() : null;
}

private static ByteArrayOutputStream runSubCommand(ByteArrayInputStream input, String command, Optional<File> dir) throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CommandLine cmd = CommandLine.parse(command);
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    if (dir.isPresent()) {
        exec.setWorkingDirectory(dir.get());
    }
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(output, output, input);
    exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    exec.execute(cmd);
    return output;
}
```