# Error while creating mysql restore cmd in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am trying to restore an mysql sql file using java, but I dont have any idea why it's not working. The code is given below.

```
/*NOTE: Getting path to the Jar file being executed*/
            CodeSource codeSource = DBmanager.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
            File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
            String jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();

            /*NOTE: Creating Database Constraints*/
            String dbName = "dth";
            String dbUser = "root";
            String dbPass = "root";

            String restorePath ="\""+ jarDir + "\\backup" + "\\" + s+"\"";


            /*NOTE: Used to create a DOS command*/
            String executeCmd = "";
            executeCmd = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql -u" + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " --database " + dbName + " < " + restorePath;


            System.out.println(executeCmd);


            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully restored from SQL : " + s);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error at restoring");
            }
```

The code executes but the java swing is stuck on the runtime command.
The line outputted by System.out.println is like this.

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -proot --database dth < "F:\Final Year Project\Final\build\backup\0_Harish_2013-02-17-20-05-12.sql"

This line works perfectly if I copy and paste it in command line. Dunno why the java swing interface just gets stuck in wait state. (The same query takes like 2 seconds on cmd and on java I have waited for 5minutes).

**Edit:**
I ran the streamgobbler and still no benefit, it still gives Exit Value: 1 which is obviously the problem IllegalThreadStateException how can I solve this?

**Edit2:**

The gobbling doesnt help as the hang still exists , heres the output of gobbler

```
OUTPUT>C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for Win32 (x86)
OUTPUT>Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
OUTPUT>affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
OUTPUT>owners.
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>Usage: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
OUTPUT>  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
OUTPUT>  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
OUTPUT>  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
OUTPUT>                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
OUTPUT>       and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
OUTPUT>         --disable-auto-rehash.
OUTPUT>                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
OUTPUT>  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
OUTPUT>                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
OUTPUT>                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
OUTPUT>                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
OUTPUT> --auto-vertical-output 
OUTPUT>                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
OUTPUT>                      result is wider than the terminal width.
OUTPUT>  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
OUTPUT>         (Enables --silent.)
OUTPUT>  --character-sets-dir=name 
OUTPUT>       Directory for character set files.
OUTPUT>  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
OUTPUT>  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
OUTPUT>                      default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
OUTPUT>
```

(rest of usage message omitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by chanding the String command to a String array command. That made the use of Gobbler redundant.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely due to you not reading from the output streams - they will block when their buffers are full. Please read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).
You may want to use something like [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html).
You also have the issue that you are tyring to use the pipe (`<`), this is a bash construct and **will not work**!
You need to create a `FileInputStream` from your file in java and set that as the `InputStream` in your code. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695664/how-to-pipe-a-string-argument-to-an-executable-launched-with-apache-commons-exec) example.

Comment: I ran the streamgobbler and still no benefit, it still gives Exit Value: 1 which is obviously the problem IllegalThreadStateException how can I solve this?