# Apache commons exec run pipe command fails

Tags: git, apache-commons-exec

I would like Apache Commons-exec to run:

> git status | head -n1 | cut -c13-

However seems it can not execute the command line and give error, Any ideas?

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse( "git status | head -n1 | cut -c13-" );
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setWorkingDirectory( file );
executor.execute( cmdLine );
```

Error:

```
error: unknown switch `n'
usage: git status [options] [--] <filepattern>...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CommandLine.parse` won't create a bash shell to interpret your pipe.

As described in "[How to pipe a string argument to an executable launched with Apache Commons Exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695664/how-to-pipe-a-string-argument-to-an-executable-launched-with-apache-commons-exec)":

> You cannot add a pipe argument (`|`) because the [here, in your case] '`git status`' command won't accept that.
>   **It's the shell (e.g. bash) that interprets the pipe and does special processing when you type that commandline into the shell**.

You should use a **`ByteArrayInputStream`** to feed the outuput of one command to another;