# Apache Commons exec input problems

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

I am attempting to pass in some plain text keys to a third party external program, and then capture the output to a string. All seems to be working, except the third party program is not accepting the input as "normal". I get an "input too long" error. but when running the same set of text to the same binary in a bash shell, it works as intended. I can't seem to find anything that would be appending extra characters.

I have been following this example : [How to pipe a string argument to an executable launched with Apache Commons Exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695664/how-to-pipe-a-string-argument-to-an-executable-launched-with-apache-commons-exec)

```
public String run(List<String> keys) throws ExecuteException, IOException{

    //String text = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), keys);  
    String text = "9714917";
    CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("/third/party/bin/program");

    Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream stdin = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(stdout, stderr, stdin);

    executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    executor.setWatchdog(new ExecuteWatchdog(10000));
    executor.execute(cmd,environment);


return stdout.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

If I'm correct this should be the same as typing in a shell

```
echo "9714917" | /third/party/bin/program
```

which works. I can get the stderr to print just fine, and even get the stdout ( which just happens to be blank since the key is rejected) Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it possible that you need to send a newline character too? (I think `echo` does.)

Comment: And I feel like an idiot. 3 days I've been fighting with this. Thanks, thats all it was!

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd party program needs a terminating new line in the input stream (as the `echo` command puts to its output), so the following should work (confirmed by @Neurobug):

```
ByteArrayInputStream stdin = new ByteArrayInputStream((text + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
```